# Find edges connected to a source node in a graph

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, sortedset

I have a java SortedSet which contains edges of a directed graph. Each element of the SortedSet is a 2 element list , first is the source node and second is the destination node. Given a source node, I want to find all the edges emerging from a source node in the best possible time complexity. How can this be done in Java.

Thanks

Comment: Is it some kind of homework ? Cause this question makes me feel like I'm doing your job while you don't even try to think about it ...

Comment: I tried it using the subset function but was unsuccessful

Comment: Can you detail what you did that didn't work ? Which comparator you used, and so on ...

Comment: Basically i thought of writing my own binary search, but figured that using a build in function would be more efficient. I tried using the subset function because in a way I want to find all elements in the sortedset where the first element is the source i.e is the source node and the second element can be anything. Using the subset function, the first parameter becomes a list which contains (sourcenode, null). But I am not able to get the second parameter of the function

Comment: If the nodes were integer values rather than java object, I would have used subset((sourcenode, null), (sourcenode+1, null)) to find all the connecting edges.

Comment: Time has clearly come for you to show some source code, cause all seems rather correct.